# image files from a directory

Tags: gtk

how do I access only image files from a directory ?(Note: directory path is being stored in the in character pointer) .the piece of code which you are going to paste should also work when any image file extension is removed.example suppose there is a Image file nature.jpg and if the extension is removed the code should work still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this python code.  Note it require gobject introspection to work

```
import gi
from gi.repository import Gio

directory_path = '.'

images = [x.get_name() for x in Gio.file_new_for_path(directory_path).enumerate_children('standard::name,standard::content-type', Gio.FileQueryInfoFlags.NONE, None) if x.get_content_type().startswith('image')]
```

That should get you a list of all images in the directory path specified.